# Simple Asp.Net Login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I just want to create a simple login page with a Response.Redirect and here's what I'm trying.  Where am I going wrong?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == "customer")
        {
        if (TextBox2.Text == "password");
        }
        Response.Redirect("Customer.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing bracket of the First if needs  to be after the redirect. Everything else is ok, besides the semi colon after the second if.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (TextBox1.Text == "customer") 
   { 
    if (TextBox2.Text == "password") 
        Response.Redirect("Customer.aspx");
   } 
}
```

Comment: @Bob happy to help